# How can I convert the hash like string to hash in ruby?

Tags: ruby, hash

The following `resp` is a string that is similar to hash in structure.

```
(rdb:1) p resp
"{\"_id\":\"4dd4eaa872f8be2d380000af\",\"account_id\":\"4dd0d71272f8be0499000009\",\"created_at\":\"2011-05-19T15:47:16+05:45\",\"line_id\":\"4dd4ea9d72f8be2d380000a5\",\"order\":{\"_id\":\"4dd4eaa872f8be2d380000b9\",\"amount\":1.2000000000000002,\"service_charge\":0.0},\"owner_id\":\"4dd0d71272f8be0499000008\",\"tenant_id\":\"4dca3f8e72f8be2950000003\",\"through_api\":true,\"title\":\"run name\",\"updated_at\":\"2011-05-19T15:47:16+05:45\"}"
```

How can I convert this into a hash?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This seems like a JSON encoded object.
Try this:

```
require 'json'
p JSON.load(resp)
```

`json` is part of Ruby 1.9, if you use 1.8 (or another Ruby implementation) you might need to install the `json` gem using `gem install json`.

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'json'
hash_a = JSON.parse(resp)

p hash_a
  {"through_api"=>true, 
   "created_at"=>"2011-05-19T15:47:16+05:45", 
   "title"=>"run name", 
   "updated_at"=>"2011-05-19T15:47:16+05:45", 
   "account_id"=>"4dd0d71272f8be0499000009", 
   "_id"=>"4dd4eaa872f8be2d380000af", 
   "owner_id"=>"4dd0d71272f8be0499000008", 
   "order"=>{"amount"=>1.2, 
   "_id"=>"4dd4eaa872f8be2d380000b9", 
   "service_charge"=>0.0}, 
   "line_id"=>"4dd4ea9d72f8be2d380000a5", 
   "tenant_id"=>"4dca3f8e72f8be2950000003"}
```